# Mirrormaker stopper due to OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am running mirrormaker in a docker container, when i run mirror maker i get below error.

> [2019-09-27 14:38:14,279] ERROR [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker
>   thread exited abnormally, stopping the whole mirror maker.
>   (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread) [2019-09-27 14:38:14,280]
>   ERROR [mirrormaker-thread-1] Mirror maker thread exited abnormally,
>   stopping the whole mirror maker.
>   (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)

Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could increase the heap by passing an environment variable.

e.g. `-e  KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx2g`